# undefined method `permit' for "**output omitted**":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to, destroy, nested-resources

Updated:
I have a link_to set up for deleting an object that is a nested resource. Prior to destroy, I have a method that checks for the instance of that object based on object_params, but the params sent keep raising `undefined method 'permit' for "asdfsadf":String` when it tries to reference the `object_params`.

Button:

```
<%= link_to content_tag('button', '', class: 'btn fa fa-trash-o focus-delete-button'), parent_object_path( :parent_id => focus.z_kf_parent, :id => focus.id, :object => focus), data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete '#{focus.name}'"}, method: :delete %>
```

Params:

```
 {"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"gmlVYHy230Y1lQY=",
 "object"=>"6c1367b1-1d63-4545-bbdb-b8ac9bd39422",
 "action"=>"destroy",
 "controller"=>"objects",
 "parent_id"=>"FA100073-4A0C-4EE0-8FB1-3EC39C61AD39",
 "id"=>"5-bbdb-b8ac9"}
```

object_params:

```
def object_params
    params.require(:set_list).permit(:id, :photographer, :digital_tech, :photo_production, :stylist, :stylist_assistant, :hair_makeup, :photographer_assistant, :name, :t_start, :t_finish, :z_kf_parent)
  end
```

Method:

```
def set_object
  binding.pry
  @object = Object.(object_id: object_params[:id]).first
end
```

Am I not setting the parameters right in the `link_to`?

Comment: I think your error is in the method `object_params`. Can you paste the contents of that method here?

Comment: @tolgap updated question with `object_params`

Comment: First off, right now you're wrapping an `<a>` tag around a `<button>` tag with the current `link_to` construction you have. What's the `content_tag(:button)` for here? You can simply assign the classes of that button to the `link_to`.

Comment: Something does not compute. That content of `params` with that code can't produce that output.

Comment: Here `"id"=>"5-bbdb-b8ac9"` is string, but `id` is defined as `int` in database.So change the code to `:id => focus.id.to_i`

Comment: @Prashant4020: hm, where you derived this from?

Comment: Oh, BTW, did you really name your model `Object`? Really really bad choice.

Comment: @Prashant4020 calling `to_i` on that string would cut it off at the first number resulting in `5`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev lol no, I didnt really name the object object

Comment: @Dan: still a bad choice. When seeking answers, one must not confuse potential answerers.

Comment: @tolgap not to leave you hanging on the `link_to` comment, I do find it odd the way the link is written ( I was style matching two other links on the same page as this one), but it does seem to be over kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `object_params` method is **requiring** there to be a param called `set_list`. There is no such parameter in your `params`.

This will work for you:

```
def set_object
  binding.pry
  @object = Object.where(object_id: params[:id]).first
end
```

You don't need to wrap a `params[:id]` lookup through a `permit` as you're not mass-assigning anything.

Comment: I tried this out and it creates the instance, but still manages to hit the `object_params` and error out.

Comment: I was being deceived! I restarted my server and it worked like a charm! Thanks much :) Also out of curiosity, if I were to maintain the `object_params`, would including `set_list` in the params solve it a different way?

Comment: Yes, but you definitely do not need something like object_params for a select query. You only need to permit attributes if youre going to do something like `Object.new object_params` so you control the attributes and no harmful attributes can be set by a user.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are attempting to use a plain hash to build an object where strong parameters are expected.

Use

```
@object = Object.where(object_params).first
```

rather than trying to push them inside a hash in the build method

**Edit**

It also appears that your link requires an update:

```
parent_object_path(set_list: {id: ..., etc})
```

since you code says it expects the set_list object.

** Previous edit was incorrect, sorry **

Comment: This still returned the same error, possibly because it is still looking for `object_params`? Also, is it possible that it is looking for a an object, but I am giving it a string?